# How do I check for compatibility between versions with the npm semver module?

Tags: node.js, semantic-versioning

Using [the semver package](https://www.npmjs.org/package/semver) I didn't see a simple way to check if I need a version of a library whether I have a compatible version. That made me wonder if I'm missing something obvious since it would seem like a common operation.

According to the [Semver.org](http://semver.org) any version that is the same or new but is not in a new *major* version is supposed to be compatible. Therefore if I need `1.2.3` and I have `>=1.2.3 <2.0.0` then it's all good. I can build that comparison by hand, it just seems so common that I'm curious if I'm missing a simpler way.

In other words, it appears I apparently have to do this

```
var canUse = function(need, have) { 
  var nextMajorVersion = semver.inc(need, 'major'); 
  return semver.satisfies(have, '>=' + need + ' && ' + '<' + nextMajorVersion); 
};
```

Which works

```
canUse('1.2.3', '1.2.3');  // true
canUse('1.2.3', '1.2.4');  // true
canUse('1.2.3', '1.3.0');  // true
canUse('1.2.3', '0.4.4');  // false
canUse('1.2.3', '2.4.4');  // false
```

Yes, it's a tiny piece of code. It just seemed like that would be such a common operation that I wouldn't have to manipulate strings and manually build a range comparison just to check what seems like it a common question, is X compatible with Y.

Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The caret operator](https://www.npmjs.org/package/semver#ranges) should create the expected range in most cases:

> `^1.2.3` := `>=1.2.3-0 <2.0.0-0`  "Compatible with `1.2.3`".  When
>     using caret operators, anything from the specified version (including
>     prerelease) will be supported up to, but not including, the next
>     major version (or its prereleases). `1.5.1` will satisfy `^1.2.3`,
>     while `1.2.2` and `2.0.0-beta` will not.

```
semver.satisfies('1.2.3', '^1.2.3') // true
semver.satisfies('1.2.4', '^1.2.3') // true
semver.satisfies('1.3.0', '^1.2.3') // true
semver.satisfies('0.4.4', '^1.2.3') // false
semver.satisfies('2.4.4', '^1.2.3') // false
```

---

The exception is with `0.x.x` versions. For these, a `^` will be ignored.

> `^0.1.3` := `0.1.3` "Compatible with `0.1.3`". `0.x.x` versions are
>     special: since the semver spec specifies that `0.x.x` versions make
>     no stability guarantees, only the version specified is considered
>     valid.

```
semver.satisfies('0.8.9', '^0.1.0') // false
```